# Q.all on NodeList in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, nodelist

I would like to perform a function on a `NodeList` object, and do the function to each in parallel. Since it's a `NodeList`, I have no `.map` or `.forEach`.

Comment: Where are you getting a NodeList from in node.js?

Comment: @Pointy In this case, requesting HTML and then putting it through `jsdom`. Then using `images = window.document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )`, for example.

Comment: What asynchronous function do you want to perform on nodes?

Comment: OK. Well you can use `[].map.call(yourNodeList, function(node) { ... })` to use the array functions. They won't do the work in parallel, however; it's just simple iteration.

Comment: @Bergi My own function which I've written to download and save images from the page, plus some other stuff. Waiting for each to finish seems really slow. Oh, it also alters the DOM and saves it again as HTML.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah, that's how the app works right now. But I feel it's too slow.

Answer (score 0):

That NodeLists don't have their own `map` function doesn't matter for parallel execution.
You just need to get your array of promises, and you can use a trivial `for` loop or use `Array.prototype.map.call` on the node list.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map.call` requires the first argument to be the `NodeList`, so I don't think I can put this in `Q.all`. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: `Q.all(Array.prototype.map.call(images, function(image){…})).then(…)`, just as you have shown in your answer. How did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
images = window.document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )

imageMapFunction = Array.prototype.map.call( images, function ( each, index ) {
    var deferred = Q.defer()

    // ... some actions
    deferred.resolve()

    return deferred.promise
})

Q.all( imageMapFunction )
.then( function () {
    // ... more stuff
}
```

Previously I had tried this, which didn't work.

```
Q.all( Array.prototype.map.call( images, function ( each, index ) {

    //... etc, same as above

}))
```

Comment: Note that `Q.Promise` is often easier to use since you don't have to think about about promises and deferreds. ES6 standard promises and Bluebird also only provide the promise constructor, so I'd recommend using that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I can't find any examples of that anywhere, have any?

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver and https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-qpromise VS http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ and https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks, looking into this. :)